# Regex for dot underscore files (._file)

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex, and I'm trying to use it to exclude dot underscore files, left all over a server of mine by OSX users.

All I've got so far is:

`^\._`

I'm not sure if this is correct, and it's something that needs to be right the first time. If someone could explain if the above is right, or if it's not, explain why it's not and what is right.

Right now I'm excluding `tmp` and `DS_Store` files, without regex, but I want to exclude `._` files. For example, `._example.txt`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `^\._` matches the string "**._**". If you use `^\._.*` then it'll match any string that begins with "**._**".

Comment: The regex is correct, we need to know the relevant code that you use this regex in, to spot the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `^` in the beginning of the regex have special meaning - that you want to match on the beginning on the input string.

E.g. 
regexp: `^John` will match `John Doe is dead` but it will not match `Doe John is dead` because in the previous input text, `John` starts the sequence

But you can use `^` character in different purpose to exclude patterns. Difference is to put it as a first characters of `()` or `[]` brackets.

Solution for your problem: `[^\._].`

Explaination:

`[^\._]` match a single character not present in the list below

`\.` matches the character `.` literally

`_` the literal character `_`

`.` matches any character (except newline)

Here is the website you can use to test your regular expresionss.
https://regex101.com/

Comment: So `[^\._].` will match anything that starts with `._`?

Comment: That will match everything except literal `.` and  literal `_`

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your input data, you can do this without regex - check for the existence of the string `._` in each file name (loop through), and if it's there, delete the file.

```js
var fileName = '._abc.blah';
if (fileName.indexOf('._') != -1) {
  console.log('remove this one');
}
```

Comment: I'm not using JavaScript.